# Parsing Formula in Report Mail Settings

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to show an email pop up window with an attached report.  I want the email fields in the popup window to be populated with the attached report's mail settings - similar to what happens when you click the "Send" button when running the report directly.  I'm trying to do this in a PXAction method.

I've got it mostly done but, I'm having a problem if the Mail Settings have a formula in them.  For instance if the Subject is set to "=[table].[field]" I get "=[table].[field]" in the Subject box for my email popup window instead of the value of table.field.

Any ideas on how to get the values of the Mail Settings fields in the report instead of the verbatim text?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what worked for me.  I'm sure there's a way to dispense with the code that removes the "=" but, this got what I needed.

```
 protected string GleanMailSetting(Report report, ReportNode reportNode, string settingText)
    {
        if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(settingText)) || (!settingText.StartsWith("=")))
            return settingText;

        string trimmedText = settingText.TrimStart(new char[] { '=' });

        PX.Common.Parser.ExpressionNode node = Reports.Parser.ReportExprParser.Parse(trimmedText, report);

        node.Bind(report.DataSource); 

        return (string)node.Eval(reportNode.DataItem); 
    }
```